# Switch command doesn't work

Tags: c, switch-statement, command, line, execution

I have to do an assignment for tommorow connected with filters. I've created the functions that I need but I have a problem with my main function which looks like this:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf ("Select program: \n1-makeLower \n2-makeUpper \n3-makeChange");
  switch(*argv[1])
  {
  case 1:
    makeLower();
    break;
  case 2:
    makeUpper();
    break;
  case 3;
    makechange();
    break;
  default;
    printf ("Error");
    break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it, an error appears "pp2.exe has stopped working". Could you guys help me solve this problem. Also, I need to use this program from the command line in order to filter some data. Did I use the `switch` command correctly? Will I be able to switch beetwen functions while working in command line?

Comment: Try `switch(argv[1][0] - '0')`.

Comment: Or more like `switch (atoi(argv[1]))`

Comment: Both work. However, neither of this is optimal as `argv` is command line arguments yet you're asking for input which `argv` is not.

Comment: You probably want something along the lines of `switch(getchar() - '0')`

Comment: Also, you want `default:` not `default;` and you don't need `break;` in your default case.

Comment: Well, switching to getchar indeed helped, but now i have diffrent problem. When i try to execute the program in command line by typing pp2.exe < myfile.txt, it doesnt work at all. Its prints all possible cases from switch and command line shuts immediately. What can i do about that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to dereference the indexed argument, indexing it dereferences the string. `*argv[1]` should be `argv[1]` - but before you can switch it, you need to convert that string to an integer.